# parity error reading from chain spec file

Tags: ubuntu, blockchain, ethereum, parity

I am using the command to create an account

```
parity --chain privatepoa-spec.json -d ~/ethereum/poa/node1/
```

And I am getting the error

```
Could not load specification file at privatepoa-spec.json: Permission denied (os error 13)
```

I changed permissions to 777 for privatepoa-spec.json, and ~/ethereum/poa/node1/
but still getting hte same error.
Tried with sudo as well and got same error

Below is the code for json

```
{
  "name": "PrivatePoA",
  "engine": {
    "authorityRound": {
      "params": {
        "blockReward": "0x4563918244F40000",
        "stepDuration": "5",
        "validators" : {
          "safeContract": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000005"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "params": {
    "gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x400",
    "maximumExtraDataSize": "0x20",
    "minGasLimit": "0x1388",
    "networkID" : "0x2323"
  },
  "genesis": {
    "seal": {
      "authorityRound": {
        "step": "0x0",
        "signature": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      }
    },
    "difficulty": "0x20000",
    "gasLimit": "0x5B8D80"
  },
  "accounts": {
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name":   "ecrecover", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 3000, "word": 0 } } } },
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "sha256", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 60, "word": 12 } } } },
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "ripemd160", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 600, "word": 120 } } } },
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "identity", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 15, "word": 3 } } } }
  }
}
```

I also have a config file, if I use the config file, I am getting same error usng parity --config node1.toml account new

```
[parity]
#chain = "privatepoa-spec.json"
base_path = "~/ethereum/poa/node1/"
[network]
port = 30301
[rpc]
port = 8545
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
interface = "0.0.0.0" #external access to rpc
[ui]
port = 8181
#[websockets]
#port = 8451
#[ipc]
#disable = true
#[account]
#password = ["node.pwds"]
#[mining]
#engine_signer = "0xaddress1..."
#reseal_on_txs = "none"
```

Below is the output of

```
sudo strace parity --chain privatepoa-spec.json -d ~/ethereum/poa/node1/


mkdir("/root/snap/parity/15610/.local/share/", 0777) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
stat("/root/snap/parity/15610/.local/share/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/root/snap/parity/15610/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/config.toml", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mkdir("/root/snap/parity/15610/.local/share/", 0777) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
stat("/root/snap/parity/15610/.local/share/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/root/snap/parity/15610/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum-updates/spec_name_override", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
unlink("/root/snap/parity/15610/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum-updates/spec_name_override") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=1024, rlim_max=1024*1024}) = 0
setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=1024*1024, rlim_max=1024*1024}) = 0
mkdir("/root/snap/parity/15610/.cache/", 0777) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
stat("/root/snap/parity/15610/.cache/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
mkdir("/root/snap/parity/15610/.local/share/", 0777) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
stat("/root/snap/parity/15610/.local/share/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
mkdir("/root/snap/parity/15610/.cache/", 0777) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
stat("/root/snap/parity/15610/.cache/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
sched_getaffinity(0, 128, [fff, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) = 8
mkdir("/root/snap/parity/15610/.cache/", 0777) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
stat("/root/snap/parity/15610/.cache/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
mkdir("/root/snap/parity/15610/.cache/", 0777) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
stat("/root/snap/parity/15610/.cache/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
mkdir("/root/snap/parity/15610/.cache/", 0777) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
stat("/root/snap/parity/15610/.cache/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
sched_getaffinity(0, 128, [fff, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) = 8
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
open("privatepoa-spec.json", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(2, "Could not load specification fil"..., 90Could not load specification file at privatepoa-spec.json: Permission denied (os error 13)) = 90
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
sigaltstack({ss_sp=NULL, ss_flags=SS_DISABLE, ss_size=8192}, NULL) = 0
munmap(0x7f24a34dc000, 8192)            = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Have you check the directory permissions for the directory in which `privatepoa-spec.json` lives?